# Bipartite Matching Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a bipartite graph $|L| = |R| = n$

Given the graph G has no perfect matching how can i prove that G has $L_1$ $\subset $  L and $R_1 \subset R
$ such that $|L_1| + |R_1| = n+1$
and $L_1$ isn't connected to $R_1$

if G have no perfect matching so there X in L (or R) such that |X| > |N(X)|
but im kinda lost how can i apply this for this proof
i will appreciate any helpers!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Let $Y=R\setminus N(X)$. We have $|X|+|Y|=|X|+|R|-|N(X)|=n+|X|-|N(X)|>n$ and $X$ isn't connected to $Y$.

Comment: thank you alot !